# App crashes on AppService with Could not load file or assembly, but works locally

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, dotnet-publish

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 app deployed in Azure AppService. After I updated `Serilog.AspNetCore` to 7th version it started crashing with:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0
```

(issue occurs only in AppService, locally everuthing works fine)

I suspect that deployment process cleans up dll's from .NET SDK similar to Azure Functions deployment flow. In Azure Functions this issue can be resolved with

```xml
<FunctionsPreservedDependencies Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll" />
```

or

```xml
<_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
```

Is there something similar for AppService?

> Note: After downgrading the package to 6th version, everything works fine

> Note 2: I don't have access to `Advanced Tools`, so cannot verify what files are being deployed (restricted by my company's DevOps)

Edit: Here's my csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>1bcc1cf7-6fce-4196-9bb5-a7aa29a04078</UserSecretsId>
    <RootNamespace>MyApp</RootNamespace>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>True</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Splunk" Version="3.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyApp.AppCore\MyApp.AppCore.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: You are deploying to Windows or Linux App Service plan?

Comment: `I don't have access to Advanced Tools`. What is the App service plan you are using ?

Comment: Could you please share your `.csproj` file .

Comment: @Harshitha I use Windows P1v2 App Service plan. Added the csproj to the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't App Service's fault, but .NET publishing (when publishing multiple project it messes up dependency versions sometimes):

- https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3886
- https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/11953

Solution in my case was to add `<IsPublishable>false</IsPublishable>` to all test projects. Foolproof way of doing it is to add `Directory.Build.targets` file containing this to the repository's root:

```xml
<Project>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(IsTestProject)' == 'true'">
    <IsPublishable>false</IsPublishable> <!-- Workaround for https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/11953#issuecomment-770434716. Try removing after .NET 8 migration -->
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded the `Serilog.AspNetCore` version to `7.0.0` and able to deploy and run the Azure App service without any errors.

[image]

- After updating the package version run and build the application to get the changes reflected in the already created bin folder.
- In your Local folder check whether you have the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` available under `Serilog.AspNetCore` =>  `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`.

[image]

- If you don't find it, install it manually from the NuGet Package and Re-deploy the App and check.

[image]

***Or***

- Try to install the package from the `Extensions` tab (If you have access).

[image]

Comment: Your app is targeting .NET 6 and uses Serilog (calls `.UseSerilog()` on host builder), and AppService uses .NET 6 runtime?

Comment: Yes..Iam using the .NET Core 6 with serilog.